# conditions for being a relation

Tags: relations

[image]

is this a relation?
does every element in set $A$ need to have an image(one or many) in set b???

[ sorry question might be too simple for most of u guys here but just started learning about relations ]

Comment: The image is a *graphical representation* of a relation, but the image itself needs to be interpreted in order to be considered a relation.  A relation from $A$ to $B$ is **any** subset of $A\times B$, proper subset or otherwise.  There is no requirement for every element of $A$ to appear as the first entry in one of the pairs in the relation.

Comment: The pictured relation from $A=\{5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ to $B=\{7,8,9,10,11,13\}$ is the relation $\{(5,7),(6,8),(7,9),(8,10),(9,11)\}$ and does indeed satisfy the definition.

Comment: "is this a relation?"  Yes.  Well, it's a *picture* of a relation.  Elements of $A$ are being matched to elements of $B$.  A relation is a collection of such matched pairs.   "does every element in set A need to have an image(one or many) in set b?" No.  Not every element of A needs to be matched from (indeed *no* elements need to be matched), not every element of B needs to be matched to.  And elements may be matched to and from multiple, single, or no times.... Now a *function* is a special type of relation, where every element of $A$ must be matched *once*, so this is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, a relation is a matching of some elements of $A$ to some elements of $B$.

Technically a relation is the the set of such matched pairs represented in a set of ordered pairs.  If $a$ is matched to $b$ then $(a,b)$ is element of the relation $R$ which is the set of all such matched ordered pairs.  And if $c$ is *not* matched to $d$ then the oredered pair $(c,d)$ is *not* an element of the set $R$.

And there is utterly *no* requirement, that every element of $A$ or that every element of $B$ gets matched.  Indeed, it'd be possible that absolutely *no* elements are matched!  That'd be the empty relation and represented by the empty set $\emptyset$.

I don't know if there is a term for a relation where every element of $A$ is matched.  There could be.  But then again that might not be an important concept.  A *function* is a special type of relation where every element of $A$ is matched *and* it is matched to *exactly* one element.  This image is not a function because not every element is matched.  But that is not a requirement for *relations* in general.

Any type of pairing between sets, including the option to *not* pair, falls into the idea of a relation.

Comment: thanks a lot !!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A = \{1,2\}$ and $B = \{c,d\}$.  As others commented, a relation is any subset of $A \times B$.  So here are some relations:

$\emptyset $

$\{(1,c) \}$

$\{(1,c), (1,d) \}$

$\{ (1,d), (2,d)\}$

$\{ (1,c), (1,d), (2,c), (2,d) \}$ (everything in $A$ is related to everything in $B$)

$\{ (2,c)\}$

$\{ (2,c), (2,d)\}$

If you restrict things so $A = B$, then you get the opportunity to have elements related to themselves (reflexive), for the order not to matter (symmetric) and so forth.  So

$\{ (1,1), (2,2)\}$ is a reflexive relation on $A \times A$.  So is

$\{ (1,1), (2,2), (1,2)\}$.

For an example of symmetric, we could have

$\{ (1,2), (2,1)\}$

And so forth.  You can make many examples.

Comment: thanks a lott!!!!!!